# What's Length annotation HBM equivalent?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I want to define a `org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length(min = 1, max = 5)`, but I have to use HBM mapping. How do I achieve the same behaviour? Ideally I'd like to use `javax.validation.constraints.Size(min = 1, max = 5)` over the first approach because it's Java API itself.

Comment: You can map the classes using .hbm.xml files and still use annotations for validation constraints

Comment: I'm confused. You cannot use HBM mapping files for validation, they are specific to Hibernate ORM. Perhaps you meant [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/reference/en-US/html/chapter-xml-configuration.html#section-mapping-xml-constraints)?

Comment: @Guillaume, I could do that, the problem is that I have a maven build that generates model classes and then erases each modification that is not contained in the HBM file.

Comment: @crizzis, no, I meant that I can only map using HBM e not annotations.

Comment: In that case, my comment still holds

Comment: @crizzis no alternative approach?

Comment: What kind of alternative approach did you have in mind? If you cannot put annotations directly in entity classes, you'll need to use `validation.xml`.

Comment: @crizzis, that's the kind of alternative. Can you provide an example with a patten vaidation and a check constraint?

Comment: See my answer. Didn't get what you meant by 'a check constraint', though

Comment: @crizzis, I meant a database check constraint mapping in vaidation. Something like https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp

Comment: Other than FK constraints and unique constraints, there's no way to add DB constraints using Hibernate. Usually, for finer-grained control over more complex DB schemas, you would switch to a DB migration tool like Flyway or Liquibase, or use a DDL script to create the schema

Answer (score 1):

HBM files are not concerned with validation.

You can use `validation.xml`, though:

**META-INF/validation.xml**

```
<validation-config>
    ...
    <constraint-mapping>META-INF/validation/constraints-myEntity.xml</constraint-mapping>
</validation-config>
```

**META-INF/validation/constraints-myEntity.xml**

```
<constraint-mappings>
    <default-package>my.package</default-package>
    <bean class="MyEntity">
        <field name="myField">
            <constraint annotation="javax.validation.constraints.Pattern">
                <element name="regexp">.*[A-Z]</element>
            </constraint>
        </field>
    </bean>
</constraint-mappings>
```